# How to reload UWP DataGrid when ItemSource is changed

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, prism

UWP DataGrid: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid)

Here is the xaml:

```
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="dg_Users"
            AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            BorderThickness="1"
            CanUserResizeColumns="False"
            GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
            IsReadOnly="True"                
            ItemsSource="{Binding UserSource, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Bound Property:

```
private ObservableCollection<User> _userSource;
    public ObservableCollection<User> UserSource {
        get { return _userSource; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _userSource, value); }
    }
```

Method:

```
//called on constructor
private async void LoadData() {
        UserSource = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        var users = await sqlService.AllUsers();

        if(users != null) {
            foreach (var item in users) {
                UserSource.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

The datagrid will display 3 items for example, then I did some changes for example added new item or removed 1 item, When I click the button that calls the LoadData(), the UserSource was changed and contains the new data, But the datagrid doesn't reload or show the new/updated data, How can I reload the DataGrid via mvvm?

Comment: As a note, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has no effect in OneWay Bindings. It is pointless to set it here.

Comment: If you always create a new collection in LoadData, there is also no point in using ObservableCollection. Just create a new collection instance, e.g. a `List<User>`, populate it, then assign it to the UserSource property, which could be `public IEnumerable<User> UserSource { ... }`. It may even be as simple as `UserSource = await sqlService.AllUsers();`.

Comment: You should also avoid `async void` methods, with the exception of event handlers.

Comment: @Clemens I changed the type of my property to IEnumerable and on my load data:
UserSource = await sqlService.AllUSers(); , and fix my problem , Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest Solution:

changed the property to IEnumerable as my AllUsers functions returns IEnumerable:

```
private IEnumerable<User> _userSource;
    public IEnumerable<User> UserSource {
        get { return _userSource; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _userSource, value); }
    }
```

Then on LoadData:

```
private async void LoadUserData() {
        UserSource = await sqlService.AllUsers();
    }
```

Thanks to @Clemens

Answer (score 2):

> How to reload UWP DataGrid when ItemSource is changed

Please avoid recreate new [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) when each button click.  please implement ObservableCollection object once then edit it. Please check the following code.

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<User> UserSource { get; } = new ObservableCollection<User>();     

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        LoadData();        
    }

    private async void LoadData()
    {
        UserSource.Clear();

        var users = await sqlService.AllUsers();

        if (users != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in users)
            {
                UserSource.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public ICommand BtnClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                UserSource.RemoveAt(0);
            });
        }
    }

}
```